# Cutting or Masking gameObject with another collider or gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I create a mask for gameObject so that it wont appear outside the boundary?

Here is the use case that i want to achieve.

[image]

Of course other way are also welcome.

As long as the brick is dynamic. Cause the user can increase the number of bricks needed as they like.

And also I am using a default renderer for this case.

Comment: you can remove the original break and put a half of it instead. If you dont have the half-brick model, sure you can achieve it with [probuilder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@5.0/manual/index.html). Also you could reduce the scale in the longitudinal axis of the brick to the half. Not good advice to play around with the scales and not a good solution though.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Is it possible to use some kind of shader(that maybe use a ZTest) in order to mask the sticking out brick ?

Comment: think it would be overcomplicating the problem. However if you are willing to dig into shaders, seems a cool exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

Rendering according to the observer'z via shaders seems a possibility. It will require more research to achieve is that way if you do not know much about shaders, and I dont see the point of that approach for the case in quuestion, that is to remove part of the geometry. I think you would use some ztest to avoid rendering occluding objects as far as I can guess, or to define which object is rendered "in front of" which, from the observer's point of view, I am not an expert though, just my opinion, meaning that this specific behaviour usually should not need to rely on shaders to be implemented. If you just need to remove part of the object, I would go for the simple approach, put it in the scene pre-broken and removing after the desired part, or remove the whole and put the partial part at the time the romaval takes place at once (for the observer the result is the same, he will not know the black witchery computer graphic tricks to make that happen) :)